# How to crack a WPA2 Password using HashCat?

Tags: security, brute-force, wpa, hashcat, opentest

I need to bruteforce a .hccapx file which includes a WPA2 handshake, because a dictionary attack didn't work. How can I do that with HashCat? I don't know about the length etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use this at your own risk. Don't do anything illegal with hashcat.

If you want to perform a bruteforce attack, you will need to know the length of the password. The following command is and example of how your scenario would work with a password of length = 8.

```
hashcat -m 2500 -a 3 capture.hccapx ?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
```

The `-a 3` denotes the "mask attack" (which is bruteforce but more optimized).

The `-m 2500` denotes the type of password used in WPA/WPA2.

The `capture.hccapx` is the .hccapx file you already captured.

The `?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d` denotes a string composed of 8 digits.

If you want to specify other charsets, these are the following supported by hashcat:

```
?l = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
?u = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
?d = 0123456789
?h = 0123456789abcdef
?H = 0123456789ABCDEF
?s = «space»!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
?a = ?l?u?d?s
?b = 0x00 – 0xff
```

Comment: what do you do if you want abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 and checking 8 or more characters? (lets say 8 to 10 or 12)?